# Prove that if $D$ is a finite integral domain, then $D$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please, check my answer to item "a" below and help me to solve item "b":

Problem: Let $D$ be an integral domain and consider $a \in D$; $a \neq 0$.

a) Show that the function $\phi_a:D \rightarrow D$; $x \mapsto ax$ is injective.

b) Use the result above to prove that if $D$ is a finite integral domain, then $D$ is a field.

Solution item a:

$x \in D \Rightarrow \phi(x)=ax$

$y \in D \Rightarrow \phi(y)=ay$

$\phi(x)=\phi(y) \Rightarrow ax=ay \Rightarrow ax-ay=0 \Rightarrow a(x-y)=0$. Since $a\neq 0$ and $D$ is a domain, then $x-y=0$, i.e.,$x=y$, hence $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: Your answer to (a) is correct. For (b): An injective map from a finite set to itself is also....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you showed that $\phi_a$ is injective. Since $D$ is finite, the map must be surjective, thus its image includes $1$.